# extract 2 values from JSON object and use as variables in loop using jq and bash

Tags: json, bash, loops, jq

I am new to jq. I am trying to write a simple script that loops through a JSON file, gets two values within each object and assigns them to two separate variables I can use with a curl REST call. I see both values as output when I echo $i but how can I get value and addr as separate variables?

```
for i in `cat /Users/egraham/Downloads/test2  | jq .[] | jq ."value,.addr"`; do
```

Comment: Could you please provide full shell code (seems to be cut after `do`) and the JSON file or at least a short sample?

Comment: for i in `cat /Users/egraham/Downloads/test2  | jq .[] | jq ."value,.addr"`; do

echo $i
done

Comment: And the JSON file?

Comment: {

"populator": { "dimension_id": "221",

    "value": “EDGE2-SYD2",

    "direction": "dst",

    "addr": “192.168.3.0/24"

   }

}

{

 "populator": { "dimension_id": "221",

    "value": “EDGE2-BOS5",

    "direction": "dst",

    "addr": “192.168.1.0/24"

   }

}

Comment: I would like to get value and addr as seperate variables so I can pass them to curl. The JSON file includes 1000s of lines with this format. I see the right output with echo $i

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
jq -rc '.populator.value + " " + .populator.addr' file.json |
while read -r value addr; do
    echo do something with "$value" and "$addr"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If spaces or tabs or other special characters make using 'read -r' problematic, and if your shell has "readarray", then it could be used:

```
$ readarray -t v < <(jq -rc '.populator | (.value,.addr)' file.json)
```

The values would then be available as ${v[0]} and ${v[1]}

This approach is especially useful if there are more than two values of interest, or if the number of values is variable or not known beforehand.

If your shell does not have `readarray`, then you can still use the array-oriented approach, e.g. along the lines of:

```
i=-1; while read -r a ; do i=$((i+1)); v[$i]="$a" ; done
```

Answer (score -1):

First:

```
for i in cat /Users/egraham/Downloads/test2 | jq .[] | jq .value; do echo $i done
```

Second:

```
for i in cat /Users/egraham/Downloads/test2 | jq .[] | jq .addr; do echo $i done
```

I don't know any way to get it without running the commands separately. I don't know AWK, but maybe it's something worth considering.

Comment: Thanks... but I need one curl statement and include both variables like this

Comment: curl -v https:///customdimension/221/populator -X POST -d '{"populator": {"dimension_id":"221","value":'$i',"direction":"src","addr":"$j"}}'

Comment: where '$i' represents value and '$j' represents addr

Comment: The two invocations of jq in 'jq .[] | jq .value' can and should be reduced to one, as in: `jq '.[] | .value`