# How to make jq to pick name value pairs

Tags: json, filter, nested, jq

Might be more or less the same ask as [How to get JQ name/value pair from nested (array?) response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510887/how-to-get-jq-name-value-pair-from-nested-array-response), but that question and example there is way too convoluted than what I'm asking --

Giving the input jason as in https://jqplay.org/s/jyKBnpx9NYX
Pick out all the name/value pair under `.QueryString, .Params` into the same unnested array

E.g., for an input of

```js
{
    "Some": "Random stuff",
    "One": {
        "QueryString": [
           { "Name": "IsOrdered",    "Value": "1"              },
           { "Name": "TimeStamp",    "Value": "11654116426247" }
        ]
    },
    "Two": {
        "QueryString": [
           { "Name": "IsOrdered",    "Value": "1"              },
           { "Name": "TimeStamp",    "Value": "11654116426247" }
        ]
    },
    "Params": [
       { "Name": "ClassName",    "Value": "PRODUCT"        },
       { "Name": "ListID",       "Value": "Products"       },
       { "Name": "Mode ",        "Value": "1"              },
       { "Name": "Dept"  ,       "Value": "5"              },
       { "Name": "HasPrevOrder", "Value": ""               }
    ],
    "And": {
        "QueryString":[]
    },
    "More": "like",
    "More+": "this"
}
```

The output would be:

```js
  [
    {
      "Name": "IsOrdered",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "TimeStamp",
      "Value": "11654116426247"
    },
    {
      "Name": "IsOrdered",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "TimeStamp",
      "Value": "11654116426247"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ClassName",
      "Value": "PRODUCT"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ListID",
      "Value": "Products"
    },
  ...
  ],
```

without any empty arrays output (`[]`), while keep the repeated values in the array.

I tried to remove empty arrays output (`[]`) by changing the jq expression from

`[( .. | objects | ( .QueryString, .Params ) | select( . != null) )]`

to

`[( .. | objects | ( .QueryString, .Params ) | select( . != null && . != []) )]`

but it failed.

And the final output need to be unnested into a single array too.

Bonus Q: Would it be possible to output each name/value pair on one line of their own like the following?

```
       { "Name": "IsOrdered",    "Value": "1"              },
       { "Name": "TimeStamp",    "Value": "11654116426247" },
       { "Name": "IsOrdered",    "Value": "1"              },
       { "Name": "TimeStamp",    "Value": "11654116426247" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Name/Value objects, one per line, you could go with:

```
jq -c '.. | objects | (.QueryString, .Params) | .. | objects | select( .Name and .Value)'
```

or more cavalierly:

```
    jq -c '.. | objects | select( .Name and .Value)'
```

Comment: Thanks peak but you missed the requirement of _"under .QueryString, .Params "_, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482586/perl-loop-within-regex-match for more details.

Comment: xpt - Please see update.

Comment: Thanks peak. Would you explain a bit why the " .. | objects" is necessary before the "select" please (ref: https://jqplay.org/s/F3qdqOd4tgl)? What problem they solved? thx!

Comment: `..|objects` yields all the JSON objects, wherever they are located. It’s something of a sledgehammer....

Comment: Thanks peak. Would you add one more bonus question to the answer please? -- apart from picking out all the name/value pair, how to add a new 3rd field to the return? basically I need `select( .Name and .Value and Required: true)`. thanks

Comment: To add the key/value, append `| . + {Required: true}`

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` must be replaced with `and`. On the result you can use `| flatten` to convert "array of arrays of objects" into just "array of objects".

Bonus A: Use the `-c/--compact-output` flag of `jq` together with `| flatten[]` instead of just `| flatten`.

Together:

```
jq -c '
[
    ..
    | objects
    | ( .QueryString, .Params )
    | select(. != null and . != [])
]
| flatten[]' input.json
```

Although this expression can be simplified into `.. | objects | .QueryString[]?, .Params[]?`
The output is:

```
{"Name":"ClassName","Value":"PRODUCT"}
{"Name":"ListID","Value":"Products"}
{"Name":"Mode ","Value":"1"}
{"Name":"Dept","Value":"5"}
{"Name":"HasPrevOrder","Value":""}
{"Name":"IsOrdered","Value":"1"}
{"Name":"TimeStamp","Value":"11654116426247"}
{"Name":"IsOrdered","Value":"1"}
{"Name":"TimeStamp","Value":"11654116426247"}
```

Comment: Perfect! 100%!!! https://jqplay.org/s/4knF9hJeTMO THX!!

Comment: This is a straightforward method that deals will all the issues that it encounters along the way. It uses many advanced features of jq, which is a good learning exercise. However, for the simplicity for people seeking memorable solutions, I'll have to pick peak's solution instead.