# jq to change one thing and filter another

Tags: json, filter, jq

Following on [How to make jq to pick name value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500269/how-to-make-jq-to-pick-name-value-pairs), which will change/transform the name value pairs. Would it be possible to filter on *another* field in the same go, or I have to pipe the result to another jq to do the extra filtering?

Here is the test data:
https://jqplay.org/s/_HqPFze-PhZ

The change/transform of the name value pairs under `.QueryString, .Params` has already been done.
Now I want to further filter the result on the `Headers` record, and would only need the fields of `Accept`, `User-Agent`, and `Referer`, and discard any other fields that might exist. I.e.,

The final result would be the same as
https://jqplay.org/s/_HqPFze-PhZ
except that the the `Headers` record now only has the `Accept`, `User-Agent`, and `Referer` remains:

```js
. . .
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Name": "Accept",
        "Value": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml"
      },
      {
        "Name": "User-Agent",
        "Value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Referer",
        "Value": "http://mytest.com/sign_in"
      }
    ]
. . .
```

Everything else should *remain the same* as the sample output.

Comment: There would be no need to invoke jq twice.  Please show the expected output, or better yet, simplify your question so that it is self-contained and requires only a small input to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @peak, I've put in the expected output. Please leave the rest of current jq express in tact and build on top of it, to work on Headers only. Otherwise, I don't know how to put them together, as I tried to put in the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500269/how-to-make-jq-to-pick-name-value-pairs, but quickly gave up. Further more it use `del` approach, which is what I'm trying to avoid, as the headers can be anything, not limited to what I have in the sample. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain as many assignments as necessary :

```
jq '( .. | objects | ( .QueryString, .Params ) | select(.) )
         |= ( map( @uri "\( .Name )=\( .Value )" ) | join("&") )
    |
    ( .. | objects | .Headers | select(.) )
         |= map(select(.Name|IN("Accept", "Referer", "User-Agent")))
   '
```

Using `walk` is more performant :

```
jq 'walk(
      ( objects | ( .QueryString, .Params ) | select(.) )
         |= ( map( @uri "\( .Name )=\( .Value )" ) | join("&") )
      |
      ( objects | .Headers | select(.) )
         |= map(select(.Name|IN("Accept", "Referer", "User-Agent")))
   )'
```